# Under utilization of worker nodes

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

While running my spark jobs on google-cloud-dataproc, I notice that only the master node is being utilized and the CPU utilization of all the worker nodes is nearly zero percent (0.8 percent or so). I have used both the GUI as well as the console to run the code. Do you know any specific reason that could be causing this and how to make the full utilization of the worker nodes?

I submit the jobs in the following manner:
 gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.executor.cores=10 --cluster cluster-663c --class ComputeMST --jars gs://kslc/ComputeMST.jar --files gs://kslc/SIFT_full.txt -- SIFT_full.txt gs://kslc/SIFT_fu
ll.txt 5.0 12

Comment: Could you tell us how you submit your job? Do you run spark-submit through SSH or submit job via gcloud/Developers Console? Does your job read from external sources? GCS?

Comment: I used both the ways:-
1. Submitting the job through the console provided at Google Dataproc. 
2. Also using the GUI.
The doesn't read any external sources. 
Following is the command I use to submit using the console.
 gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.executor.cores=10 --cluster cluster-663c --class ComputeMST --jars gs://kslc/ComputeMST.jar --files gs://kslc/SIFT_full.txt -- SIFT_full.txt gs://kslc/SIFT_fu
ll.txt 5.0 12

Comment: Thanks for info. I think your next step would be to use a [web interface](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces) to look at Spark Job's UI to find out exactly what its doing. Its not unreasonable for a job to not use workers for some portion of its execution.